# Catch error, when not finding getElementById

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I am scrapping some data from a webpage and want to switch my `id`, when one id is not found.

I tried:

```
If IsError(Docx.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice").innerText) Then
    price = Docx.getElementById("priceblock_saleprice").innerText
Else
     price = Docx.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice").innerText
End If
```

However, I get an error at `IsError(Docx.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice").innerText)` with `Object variable or With Block is not set.`

Any suggestion, how to "catch" the error at `Docx.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice").innerText`?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to target elements by ID, your choices of a non-destructive catch are limited but you can `Set` the return of the `getElementById` and check for nothing.

```
dim el as MSHTML.IHTMLElement

on error resume next
set el = Docx.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice")
on error goto 0
If not el is nothing  Then
    price = Docx.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice").innerText
Else
    price = Docx.getElementById("priceblock_saleprice").innerText
End If
```

If you target elements by collections, you can loop through them looking for a second unique identifier before accessing one of their properties (e.g. .innerText).

Answer (score 3):

Try use `IsObject Funcion` -> [IsObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251535.aspx)

In your case `IF IsObject(Docx.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice")) THEN (...)`

Comment: Your link ended up malforming. There's an extra `ps//` in it.